# How to select the document, which my data is in its Array type field

Tags: mongoid

I have a model like this:

```
class Region
field :country, type: Array
end
```

If I have the country name, for example 'US', I want to select the object, which has the 'US' in its :country field.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for

```
Region.any_in(:country => ['US'])
```